# Creating an administrator without access to other administrator accounts

Tags: macos, user-accounts, administrator

I want to create an administrator account on my laptop that does not have access to other administrator accounts.

In the `sudo visudo` file

```
# root and users in group wheel can run anything on any machine as any user
root            ALL = (ALL) ALL
#%admin         ALL = (ALL) ALL
my-user       ALL = (ALL) ALL
```

What I am trying to do here is to allow only sudo from my account and not the other administrator. This is what I have done so far, but I am not sure if it is enough (or will even work to begin with to be honest).

Comment: Fundamentally, any user in the sudoers file will be able to give themselves access to programs and files.  You can do things like restrict file permissions to block casual browsing of restricted files, but if a user is present in sudoers, then they can just run "sudo su" to have full access.  What's your goal : to prevent access to specific files/folder ?  To prevent running specific applications?

Comment: The user in my example is not present. I have a third account named "PseudoAdmin". I have only whitelisted root and my-user in the sudo file.

The goal is essentially creating an account that looks like an administrator, but does not have the ability of looking at my personal files.

Comment: It would help if OP explained the circumstances.  Is this Mac public property, shared with someone, or OP's alone?  If it's OP's alone, is it in a lockable room?  If it's shared, is PsuedoAdmin for a friend to physically access the Mac, Remote Desktop, File Sharing, or SSH?  What does "looks like an administrator" mean to you?  Pretend you're an attacker - what tests would you do to determine admin status?  If OP is hoping an attacker will have a brief look, not see Important Files, and give up, I suggest Googling "security by obscurity."

Comment: Fair enough, sorry. Basically this is a shared laptop where person A has requested me to create an admin account, strictly for policy reasons. I, person B, want to follow the policy while restricting this account from possibly reaching into my own private portion of the laptop.

  It might be worth noting that no one would be using the new account, it is strictly for policy reasons. The initial intention with the account was to create a separate account that would be backed up (again, this is all policy) while leaving our personal accounts in peace.

Comment: Good.  The answer provided by music2myear is correct.  Any administrator will be able to view all files on the machine, so you will have to trust all the people who have that password.  If you want a little privacy, you will need to have a machine that you own that you alone control.  There's many other security considerations, but that's the start.

Comment: Go ahead and post a new question with your newly clarified question. We've answered this one, but it seems your "real" question was lying underneath it all and we've just now found it out. It deserves its own place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being an administrator means, fundamentally, the ability to change permissions, including their own.

This means that if you grant someone administrator but attempt to limit their permissions on certain parts of the system they will be able to change those permissions themselves to suit their desires.

Instead of trying to reign in or limit and control administrator rights, you should expand limited/normal user rights for these users to include the aspects they require while preventing full admin.

Comment: Ok, thanks. To re-angle the question. Say my account was blacklisted in the sudo file, how would I get around that?

Comment: Post that as a new question. Make sure to include any relevant information, such as whether this is a corporate computer and what rights you typically have on the device.